# drop_duplicates in pandas when duplicate is only in first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first column, say A, has duplicates, the second does not.

I have tried

```
df["A"].drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

but that returns the same number of rows.
How can I drop the rows where the value in column "A" is the same?

Example:

```
John Miller
John Smith
Mark Robinson
Jeffrey Robinson
```

should return

```
John Miller
Mark Robinson
Jeffrey Robinson
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `subset`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A'],inplace=True)
print (df)
         A         B
0     John    Miller
2     Mark  Robinson
3  Jeffrey  Robinson
```

Docs:

> **subset** : column label or sequence of labels, optional
>
> Only consider certain columns for identifying duplicates, by default use all of the columns

Comment: Great, this is what I wanted.